# Is there a calendar NOT based on a solar or planetary cycle?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I'm wanting to find a calendar system that would be used by a space faring race but can't think of how I would even google that?!

Comment: StarTrek stardate before the reboot movie uses a calendar that is based on the TV series production cycle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardate

Comment: Vernor Vinge talks about one in *Deepness in the Sky*. It's based on Earth seconds, people talk about kiloseconds (an hour being about 3), megaseconds, and gigaseconds.

Comment: @John_O I just started reading that last night after seeing your response. Looking forward to both the story and the calendar! Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking a lunar calendar qualifies (since the Moon is not a planet), but I don't suppose that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the general term your looking for is "metric" calendar or "decimal" time. However, most of the Earth based ones that have been tried are still tied to the solar year and lunar month - such as the [French Republican Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_Calendar).

Then again - we do have the Unix timestamp, which is simply the number of seconds since the 1st of January 1970. This is actually the reference date that the far-into-the-future  'programmer-archaeologist' in Vernor Vinge's novel, A Deepness in the Sky. However, leap seconds are still inserted (the Earth randomly slows down or speeds up a little because of movement in its mass) - so, it's not quite independent of Earth time.

As for fictional types - Wikipedia actually has a fair few examples in the [Decimal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time#Decimal_times_in_fiction) article

Comment: This is what I was looking for. My Wikipedia search skills were not up to snuff for finding what I wanted. Thank you so very much! I love it... I hope that if anyone knows of any others that they still post those too...

Comment: Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) includes leap seconds, International Atomic Time (TAI) does not. Unix uses UTC. Of course relativity has time flowing at different rates depending on acceleration/gravity and velocity, so even such a standard would need an arbitrary rate as well as unit and starting point.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have an explicit answer, but maybe this can help you find your answer.

There are not many candidates for the basis of such a time system.  Every time system must be based on some observed event, which happens at a regular rate or interval.  For obvious reasons, the rotation of the Earth, and the orbit of the Earth and moon are the basis for our calendar, and by dividing these units, the basis for all of our time measurements.

Any other calendar must also measure a consistent event or cycle.

The two I can imagine are:

1. Radioactive decay

   Obviously, real scientists do this, most commonly by way of [Carbon-14 dating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating).

   And certainly science fiction stories have capitalized on the idea of radio active decay to determine the timing of things--since real science does this.

   However, I am not aware of any sci-fi universe where a *calendar* or other absolute units of time are based on radioactive decay.  But it could certainly be done; and perhaps has been done.

   Note that Carbon-14 wouldn't need to be used, and probably wouldn't be the most obvious choice, considering it's very long half-life.  Such a calendar would probably be based on an element with a half-life measured in seconds, hours, or days, then divided down or multiplied out to the desired granularity.

   The only other thing missing to form a calendar is a starting point, which would simply have to be arbitrary, or extrapolated back to the estimated beginning of the universe.
2. The timing of a natural phenomenon

   An obvious example might be a "light meter"--that is, the time it takes light to travel one meter.  However, this has the problem of coming up with a unit of length measure that isn't [defined by celestial bodies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre).

   The most obvious way to do that is to measure how far light travels in a certain time... but then you need a universal definition of time measure.

And one last piece that is necessary for any calendar:  A starting point.  The birth of Christ, the ascension of a new leader, the day the Enterprise was launched, etc...

Any such event will be arbitrary (by some standard). The only non-arbitrary, universal beginning of a calendar would be, I suspect, the beginning of the universe.  In real life, this is not known precisely enough to model a calendar.  In your sci-fi universe, it may or may not be.

But in your sci-fi universe, you will probably just choose an arbitrary starting point--the day your race started a new colony, the date of a supernova, the end date of a war, etc.

Comment: @Flimzy thank you for an amazingly well thought-out response. I would call this question answered except it doesn't give me what I'm hoping for... an example calendar. Which brings up a dilemma... what if there isn't such a calendar? My goal in all of this is for a story I'm writing, rather than dream up a calendar with my fairly un-scientific mind (I was raised in religious schools, so my science education included fairy tales like adam and eve in them... ugh.) I was hoping to find a well thought out, scientifically based example and run with it...

Comment: @randomblink: The main reason I suspect we don't use other calendars in sci-fi is that the audiences are all humans, and all use earth calendars (see Jersey's answer). So you'd still want some point of reference with your readers. If I were writing a story of that sort, I would use radioactive decay as the basis for my calendar, based on an element whose half-life one earth day, or an even number of earth days day--for consistency with your readership.

Comment: @randomblink: As for how to handle your question, if your true question is "How could I build a calendar not based on orbits?" you could just modify your question, to make my answer (and/or Jersey's) fit, then accept the one you find most helpful.

Comment: @Flimzy as much as I respect that answer (being a massive sci-fi book consumer) and am familiar with that, I really want to play with the calendar. Like use it for a shirt, maybe a tattoo even (put my birthday in that calendar time or something). The one thing about Star Trek that always stood out to me was the 'stuff.' Those things that 'stood out' like the Star Date, the oddly shaped spaceships, and more. I am trying to engender a connection based on a workable calendar that screams MY story.

Comment: I am hoping to find a calendar/clock schedule that would make sense for both colony ships (and their AI's) that needed to track time and the humans that need a regular schedule for historical tracking and planning of events and activities. Also, if I can find a system that works for me, and clicks just right... I'm hoping to use it in interesting ways... t-shirts, icons, javascript counters for the website, etc.

Comment: @randomblink: Sounds like an interesting project!

Comment: If I were a space faring race.. I'd set my clocks / calendar to a pulsar in / near my local system. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'm going to go flip-side on this, and NOT recommend a different time scale. As we are creatures of habit, it would be perfectly natural for a species to keep to a unit of measure that they are most familiar with. Just look at the differences between the SI/metric system, and those who grew up with them. I know the SI System by heart, and can gauge it great. A Kilometer? A Kilogram? Not so much. Though it would be hard to gauge the passing of time in an eternal night of space, our bodies still biologically run on the 24-hour solar day. One might be able to train themselves to change this *slightly* (like a 20-hour day or a 27 hour day) but a radical change would probably be biologically impossible for us.

As for an actual 'paper' calender, things such as dates for the passing of time, unless your/the idea is a good deal further into the future, people are still going to be stuck 'thinking' of what their calander is. And remember, there is quite a few different calenders out there, though I believe almost all are either measured off the solar year or the lunar year.

You might want to look up an actual 'solar' day (a period of time in which the sun makes a full rotation). I don't know the lapse of time, though I do know it is greater than 23.98 hours. Of course, it would be hard to change 'time' as we measure the light year and the parsec by our measurements of time and distance. Unless you want to reinvent the light year, I would suggest sticking with Terran Standard to avoid a lot of confusion when it comes to simple measurements such as seconds and minutes.

You could always frame it in a different way to make it exotic, such as the Star Date from Star Trek. today could be 2013.07.08 and include a time stamp (like 2013.07.08:08.30Z). Easy and effective. Or just change the names of the calander months (as I doubt the Jewish and the Arab calander calls this month July).

Comment: See and for this story it's a post-colonization... mankind is in another universe from their seeder ships... so I could always frame it off of the Leave Earth date, but I'm also using AI's as intermediaries in decision making processes. So I really feel like a different system would be selected. Granted, the new planet will have it's own calendar, seasons, day and night times... but I wanted a calendar for the in-between years... something the AI's would use always because it was independent of a planet or solar system.

Comment: A two-calander system is totally possible and plausible. I would recommend (since I assume the species is human) that the human calander be as 'human' ie Earth-like as possible, just so the readers aren't confused. For the Machines, I would pick something logical, like the Unix Time Code (though it doesn't have to start on 1/1/70) since that would make more sense to machines... and who would gauge time in seconds, anyhow? Calculate everything by the power of ten, and you got yourself a nice, albeit unusual, calander.

Comment: I'm envisioning the AI's referencing the more efficient system (like computers do the UTC) and convert for the less technical humans as needed. I'll be referencing Earth time, the Computer time, and the new planet time. I really don't want to jack those up so my thoughts are to write my timeline in regular current fashion... 01 JAN 2013 13:01:13 and then convert between them as needed... but first I need something to convert between.

Comment: @Jersey: Why use powers of 10? If the space-faring race in question isn't human, they probably don't count by 10s. Binary might make more sense.

Comment: @Keith the ten code can be swapped between Metric (as everything is in the power of ten) and binary (as everything is coded in 1's and 0's, and is known as the 10 code). For a computer, this would make the most logical choice.

Comment: @Random as a writer myself, I suggest simplicity itself; don't confuse the reader or yourself, since you'll be doing the math! Perhaps invent a new time zone for your new planet, and make a 'conversion' for it (like GMT -8.75) and then throw a multiplier (like x1.2) because the day is longer on a, say 30 hour day planet. Julius Caeser made the Julian Calander, and they had to add something like a permanent month, and extra 20 days for five years, and five temp days every twenty years for leap year. It doesn't necessarily have to make that much sense, and might even add a little oomph to it?